# Why do we sit in the sukkah in the autumn?

Tags: sources-mekorot, sukkot, weather, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

I remember hearing at some point that there's a disagreement between the Ashkenazi and Sefardi rishonim regarding why we sit in the sukkah in the autumn:

- Ashkenaz - Because we love God, so we go out into the cold
- Sefarad - Because God loves us, so He has us sit out in the lovely autumn weather

Are there sources to support this?

Comment: It fits with the geography.

Comment: @DoubleAA I know. I hope there are sources to back it up, though.

Comment: [When else would we sit in the sukkah?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/16594/edit)

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure that link is pointing where you want?

Comment: It is just fine. I think your question is weaker without justification that autumn is unique. You only need to point out that one might have thought it would be in the spring with pesach, but it was moved. Now why was it moved davka to autumn? etc.

Comment: LOL............

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a German source in the [Tur, Orach Chayyim 625](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14268&st=&pgnum=532&hilite=):

[image: tur on sitting in the sukka]

```
"...in the seventh month, when it's rainy, and people generally leave their summer shade 
huts and go into their houses, we leave our houses and sit in our huts so that everyone 
will see that it's because of the commandment of The King to do so."
```

And a friend pointed me to a Mediterranean source in the [Rambam, Moreh Nevuchim 3:43](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9463&st=&pgnum=106):

[image: rambam on sitting in the sukka]

"...we sit in the sukkah at a time when it can be enjoyed, without great heat or distressing [cold] rain."

Comment: Beautiful! +one

Comment: @msh210 Thanks! I've been recounting this discussion without sources for a while, and I'm glad to have dug up some references.